# Can a minor traditionally publish their novel?

Tags: publishing, young-author, traditional-publishing

I'm a minor who's working on the second draft of my novel (the first was about 77k words). Can I traditionally publish my it when it's done? If so, then will my parents get credit for it instead of me since they'll probably have to sign the contracts?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before. Look at the answers under these questions: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/33234/how-to-get-my-book-taken-seriously-as-a-teenager, https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/19194/i-am-a-16-year-old-who-wants-to-be-a-writer-but-can-i and https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/is-it-okay-to-publish-a-book-at-a-young-age

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get my book taken seriously as a teenager?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/33234/how-to-get-my-book-taken-seriously-as-a-teenager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of works for hire, copyright is owned by the author, until and unless the author assigns it to someone else. There is hardly ever a good reason to do this, so don't do it.

If a minor signs a contract, they are not held to the same standard as adults. Of course, this makes the age of the minor a factor. This means that publishers may be reluctant to enter into a contract with a minor since the minor can't be compelled to fully comply with the terms of the agreement. It is more than likely a publisher will require the guardian of the minor to sign the contract.

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty certain Christopher Paolini was only 15 when his first novel, Eragon, was published, and Clare North/Kate Griffin/Catherine Webb was only 14 when Mirror Dreams came out. In my albeit limited experience, publishers want a story they can sell, doesn’t matter who wrote it. You’ll probably have a harder time finding an agent to represent you than persuading a publisher to buy your book, and your age might actually become a the hook they sell it by.